# Android Studio Which one should be use - Android Test folder or main for adding new java classes

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android studio.

I created new project and find that there are two folder name - **Android test** and **MAIN** which folder should I use to add new classes and packages. These folder are organized in same ways, means my package name folders are in both.

Comment: Put your classes and packages inside src > main >java . Don't put them inside the test folder.

Comment: [Check this](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) out for android directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

main/java/your/package/directory/tree for your application classes, test is root for unit/instrumental tests' classes